# How to programmatically call iOS from within a mac os x application

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, bluetooth

I would like to have have "remote" control from my osx application over an iOS application that exposes itself for calling via its own custom url scheme. I would also like the osx application to be able to read data back from the iOS application.

The iOS application can be running on an iOS device that is paired with osx device via either: (a) bluetooth (b) on the same wireless network. In other words, it can be assumed that the two devices will be next to each other for the interaction.

Comment: I should add: I will not have control over the codebase of the iOS application - it is a 3rd party application that can only be called via the custom url scheme.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to embed an HTTP server in your iOS app.

I have done exactly this in the past, [using this excellent framework](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer).

The iOS server can even appear as a local Bonjour service that magically appears in Safari's Bonjour's bookmark.

Comment: Would this require installing an app on iOS that is hosting this HTTP server?

Comment: No. This is a framework that you embed inside your iOS app. You need to add a couple of lines or so in your "didFinishLaunching" app delegate method, and you're all set. Read the docs. It simple enough to get going, and transform your iOS app into a WebServer that is accessible over Bonjour throughout your local network.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do so in the latest iOS8 and OS X Yosemite using [Handoff](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/Handoff/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: I suspect this would require having access to the source & publication of the iOS app (which is not the situation I am in). To use Handoff it seems that both applications need to be sharing their data via iCloud.